# IE doesn't show repeated word in CSS backround

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to have a word repeated in all the page's background. The CSS code I have here works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE 10 and 11 it doesn't  show at all. Any suggestions on how to make this work in IE as well. I take any other better solution as well.

```css
.textmarked::before {
  position: fixed;
  top: -75%;
  left: -75%;
  display: block;
  width: 300%;
  height: 300%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  content: attr(data-textmark);
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.60;
  line-height: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #FF0000;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="textmarked" data-textmark="JUST DATA ONLY">
  Content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.textmarked::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  content: attr(data-textmark);
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.60;
  line-height: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="textmarked" data-textmark="JUST DATA ONLY">
  Content here
</div>
```

Comment: This is the rest of the code I am using to replicated the background across the entire  page:

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.textmarked')).forEach(function(el) {
       el.dataset.textmark = (el.dataset.textmark + ' ').repeat(10000);
    });

Comment: start by removing the z-index rule. a value of -1 places it below the body (z-index 0)... ::before, ::after cascade, they should automatically appear at the current top z-index. To debug your css rules, use the DOM Explorer tab of the dev tool. You can disable style rules one by one to find out which rule is causing a problem. If these are @media print rules, you must turn on background image/color printing(in print preview too)